# How insert image in a email without call url and without use attachment?

Tags: php, html, email

Looking for html-email format, how i can include a jpeg-image (logo) in a email without call absolute address from website and without put it as attachment in it?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use a data: url as the src of the image: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: Like something as copy/paste jpeg-file inside tag <img> ?

Comment: Like you have to transform the image data to base64 encoding and paste this as part of the url in img tag.

Comment: ok thanks! i will try.

Comment: You can use img src method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to read the contents of the image and transfer them to data uri which you can "inline" into the html like this:

```
$image_data=file_get_contents("some_image.jpg");
$encoded=base64_encode($image_data);
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,{$encoded}'>";
```

Of course you will not echo the image tag, you just ineed to put it into the email with your preferred mailer client.

Comment: Using base64 may work in some email clients, but it is not supported by some major email clients: https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/